# Filter a django model by comparing two foreign keys

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I need to create a filter in Django by comparing two foreign keys to each other. The double-underscore syntax only works on the left hand side of the equation. So whatever is on the right side throws an error:

```
match = UserProfile.objects.filter(
    user__date_joined__gte = group__date
)
```

Django (or python here) doesn't interpret group_*date as a parseable variable name, and complains that it's not defined. I can switch the variables around, and then user*_date_joined would be undefined. (the variable names here are just an example)

What I'm trying to achieve would look like this in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM profile p, user u, group g WHERE
    p.u_id = u.id AND
    u.group_id = g.id AND
    u.date_joined >= g.date
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to use [F() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#django.db.models.F) to do this

```
from django.db.models import F

match = UserProfile.objects.filter(user__date_joined__gte = F('group__date'))
```